# How to change the data template in runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatemplate

In my application, I have a `CheckBox` in it, I would like when it's checked, show one `DataTemplate` and when it's unchecked, show another one.

Here is the snippet with the two templates

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow_1" ItemsSource="{Binding Item3}"
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentId}"/>
            </DataTemplate>                
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

I'm not sure how to implement it, but I supposed that I need the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my User control to fire or just determine when has changed.

Comment: Lookup `DataTemplateSelector`, I think that it should fit your need nicely.

Comment: Ok, that's not my real doubt, I mean, i would like that inmediable when checkbox state changes, fire th data template selector

Comment: I see. Well, one option would be to create a class derived from `ContentControl` with say three dependency properties: two of type `DataTemplate` for the templates, and one `bool` to bind to `CheckBox.IsChecked`. This control can then set the appropriate template depending on the value of `Boolean`-property and also update the template when the dependency property is changed. You then place an instant of this class in the `DataTemplate` of the `RowHeaderTemplate` and add the appropriate bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only via triggers. If the above thing is your requirement. You can do it simply via triggers. I tried and it worked for me.

```
   <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyRowHeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock x:Name="RowHeaderTxt" 
                   Text="{Binding StudentId, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox}" 
                         Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="RowHeaderTxt" Property="Text" 
                        Value="{Binding FullName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Item3}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource MyRowHeaderTemplate}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Try this.